# Can’t find Xcode install for Metal compiler

Tags: macos, operating-system, unreal-engine5

Not able to launch `Unreal Engine` even after installing `Xcode` and accepting the license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the following command, after successful installation of Xcode

```
 sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```